# Groovy shell concatenate Strings

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

I am trying to concatenate two strings using groovy shell but it's not working

```
   groovy.shell("def name = 'MyName'; def fname = 'firstName'; println name+fname" );
```

But for single string this is working

```
   groovy.shell("def name ='MyName'; println name");
```

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use StringBuilder as below
Object value = shell.evaluate("def name= new StringBuilder('James'); def fname= new StringBuilder('abd'); println name.append(fname) ;");